# Different Behaviour adding new line while sending email from GMAIL app and Google MAIL app

Tags: java, android, email

I need to send email from my android app and I am using the following code to send it :

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                emailIntent.setType("text/html");
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"abc@gmail.com"});
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Test Subject");
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getBody());
                try {
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail"));
                } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

 private String getBody() {
        StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder();
        body.append("Hi Team,").append("\n\n");
        body.append("Test body :").append("\n\n");

        return body.toString();
    }
```

when I send it from GMAIL app "\n" is working fine but when I send it via MAIL app "\n" is not inserting a new line.
Has anybody experienced the same before.

I have tried text/html, text/plain, ACTION_SENDTO, System.getProperty("line.separator"), 
 but nothing is working for MAIL app.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Line breaks in emails use CRLF (`"\r\n"`). Still, I'd say it's a bug if an email app ignores non-CRLF newlines in `EXTRA_TEXT`.

If you specifically want to send emails consider using [`ACTION_SENDTO`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SENDTO). It was created for just this use case. One advantage compared to `ACTION_SEND` is that only email apps show up in the chooser dialog. If you want to learn more about why `ACTION_SENDTO` is preferable read the article [Sending Email using Intents](https://medium.com/@cketti/android-sending-email-using-intents-3da63662c58f#.vanql0qif).

The only downside of `ACTION_SENDTO` is that it can be tricky to create a well-formed `mailto:` URI. But you could use the library [EmailIntentBuilder](https://github.com/cketti/EmailIntentBuilder) to create such intents. It takes care of all the encoding, including converting `"\n"` to the proper `"\r\n"`.

```
EmailIntentBuilder.from(getActivity())
    .to("abc@gmail.com")
    .subject("Test Subject")
    .body("Hi Team,\n\nTest body :\n\n")
    .start();
```

Comment: I'm using above mentioned EmailIntentBuilder version 2.0.0. But it is not working. Can you pls help?

Comment: @LincyTonita: "it is not working" is not much of an error report. Feel free to create an issue in the repository with as many details as possible. Ideally provide some sample code to reproduce the issue you're observing. https://github.com/cketti/EmailIntentBuilder/issues

Comment: It is not working wrt to this question.. New line is not getting added when I use \n.. Yes i ll add details in repo. Thank you for your time..

Comment: I am seeing the same thing. On a Samsung S3 Tab, GMail version 2020.05.31.317831277 (showing as the latest release in the Play Store for this device) I am sending a string with "\n\n", and no newline at all is getting created (much less two of them).